# Error: 503 DNS resolution failed in Google Translate API but ONLY when executing the Python file via terminal

Tags: python-3.x, api, google-cloud-platform, cron, google-translate

I am running into a strange issue when using Google Translate API with a JSON authorization key. I can run the file without any issue directly in my editor of choice (VSCode). No errors.

But when I run the same file via terminal, the file executes up until after loading the Google Translate credentials from disk. The call then throws below error message.

Since this only ever happens when running the file from terminal, I find this bug hard to tackle.

The goal is to then have this file collect data and translate some of the fields using Google services, then store the data in a data base.

Below is the error message:

```
    Error: 503 DNS resolution failed
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/MY-USER-NAME/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/api_core/grpc_helpers.py", line 57, in error_remapped_callable
      File "/home/MY-USER-NAME/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/grpc/_channel.py", line 690, in __call__
      File "/home/MY-USER-NAME/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/grpc/_channel.py", line 592, in _end_unary_response_blocking
    grpc._channel._Rendezvous: <_Rendezvous of RPC that terminated with:
            status = StatusCode.UNAVAILABLE
            details = "DNS resolution failed"
            debug_error_string = "{"created":"@1584629013.091398712","description":"Failed to pick subchannel","file":"src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/client_channel.cc","file_line":3934,"referenced_errors":[{"created":"@1584629013.091395769","description":"Resolver transient failure","file":"src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/resolving_lb_policy.cc","file_line":262,"referenced_errors":[{"created":"@1584629013.091394954","description":"DNS resolution failed","file":"src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/resolver/dns/c_ares/dns_resolver_ares.cc","file_line":370,"grpc_status":14,"referenced_errors":[{"created":"@1584629013.091389655","description":"C-ares status is not ARES_SUCCESS: Could not contact DNS servers","file":"src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/resolver/dns/c_ares/grpc_ares_wrapper.cc","file_line":244,"referenced_errors":[{"created":"@1584629013.091380513","description":"C-ares status is not ARES_SUCCESS: Could not contact DNS servers","file":"src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/resolver/dns/c_ares/grpc_ares_wrapper.cc","file_line":244}]}]}]}]}"
    >
```

This is the relevant part of my code:

1. Dedicated CRON file (I use this two-step setup in many other projects without any issue)

```
#! anaconda3/bin/python

import os 
os.chdir(r'/home/MY-USER-NAME/path-to-project')

import code-file
```

2. Code file (simple .py script)

```
[...]

from google.oauth2 import service_account
from google.cloud import translate

key_path = 'path-to-file/credentials.json'
credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
key_path, scopes=['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform'])

def translate_to_en(contents, credentials=None, verbose=False, use_pinyin=False):

            [...]

            client = translate.TranslationServiceClient(credentials=credentials)  
            parent = client.location_path(credentials.project_id, 'global')

            [...]

            response = client.translate_text(
              parent=parent,
              contents=[contents],
              mime_type='text/plain',  # mime types: text/plain, text/html
              target_language_code='en-US')

            [...]


[...]

for c in trans_cols:
    df[f'{c}__trans'] = df[c].apply(lambda x: translate_to_en(contents=x, credentials=credentials, verbose=False))

[...]
```

If there is anyone with a good idea to solve this, your help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the issue is relevant to the grpc [bug](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/20972) reported in github. For gRPC name resolution, you can follow [this doc](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/doc/naming.md) on github.